# In Kotlin, how can I work around the inherited declarations clash when an enum class implements an interface?

Tags: enums, interface, kotlin

I define an enum class that implements Neo4j's `RelationshipType`:

```
enum class MyRelationshipType : RelationshipType {
    // ...
}
```

I get the following error:

`Inherited platform declarations clash: The following declarations have the same JVM signature (name()Ljava/lang/String;): fun <get-name>(): String fun name(): String`

I understand that both the `name()` method from the `Enum` class and the `name()` method from the `RelationshipType` interface have the same signature. This is not a problem in Java though, so why is it an error in Kotlin, and how can I work around it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

it is a [[image]kotlin](/questions/tagged/kotlin)  [bug-KT-14115](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-14115) even if you makes the `enum` class implements the **interface** which contains a `name()` function is denied.

```
interface Name {
    fun name(): String;
}


enum class Color : Name;
       //   ^--- the same error reported
```

**BUT** you can simulate a `enum` class by using a `sealed` class, for example:

```
interface Name {
    fun name(): String;
}


sealed class Color(val ordinal: Int) : Name {
    fun ordinal()=ordinal;
    override fun name(): String {
        return this.javaClass.simpleName;
    }
    //todo: simulate other methods ...
};

object RED : Color(0);
object GREEN : Color(1);
object BLUE : Color(2);
```

Answer (score 0):

The example above is working with an interface having a property `name` instead of a function `name()`.

```
interface Name {
    val name: String;
}

enum class Color : Name {
    Blue
}
```

Comment: While I understand the downvote, as it is not helping with 3rd party interfaces like RelationshipType, it is a way to use an enum's name in an interface.