# Jooq kotlin EnumType

Tags: postgresql, kotlin, jooq

Is there a way in kotlin for an enum class to extend Jooq's `EnumType` ?

I get a compile error since EnumType has an abstract getName method and so does Kotlin enum class.

```
Error:(96, 5) Kotlin: Inherited platform declarations clash: The following declarations have the same JVM signature (getName()Ljava/lang/String;):
    fun <get-name>(): String defined in com.xyz.MyEnum.Val1
    fun getName(): String defined in com.xyz.MyEnum.Val1
```

If I use a regular Kotlin class instead of enum class then Jooq fails with the error:

```
Error while looking up Scala enum
ClassNotFoundException ...
```

Can Jooq + Kotlin + Postgresql Enums play nicely?

Comment: According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44553992/1853785) is not possible, have you tried to use sealed class instead to see if it works?

Comment: Thanks, good to know that @OmarMainegra.

Comment: enum class internally extends java.lang.enum class. So, you can't extend that further